# Auto translate word/excel document to english with Google Translate for documents using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, document, google-translate, getelementsbyname

I have written a sample code that opens the Google Translate webpage for Documents and automates click events to upload (Browse files) word/excel file, generate translated document and download it to local folder.

The problem is that i have to manually select the file from the Open File dialog that appears. Ultimately, i want to loop thru a folder and automate sending files in that folder for translation.

- Is there a way that the files are automatically selected in the filename textbox of the fileOpen dialog without user intervention?
- Is there a way to auto download the translated files to a specified folder?

```
Option Explicit

Sub TranslateAndDownload()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Dim FileToTranslate As String
    Dim TranslatedFileLink As String
    Dim oHTML_Element
    
    ' URL of Google Translate with parameters for auto-detect source language and target English
    URL = "https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&op=docs"
    
    ' Path to the file you want to upload for translation
    FileToTranslate = "C:\Users\Doctor\French_Test.docx"
    
    ' Create a new Internet Explorer instance
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    
    ' Navigate to the Google Translate URL
    IE.Navigate URL
    
    ' Wait until IE finishes loading the page
    Do While IE.busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ' Upload the file for translation
    For Each oHTML_Element In IE.Document.getElementsByName("file")
        If oHTML_Element.className = "ZdLswd" Then
           oHTML_Element.Value = FileToTranslate
            oHTML_Element.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next oHTML_Element
        
    ' translate document
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") ' Wait for 05 seconds
    For Each oHTML_Element In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-Bz112c-M1Soyc nCP5yc AjY5Oe LQeN7 k2RlOb")
        oHTML_Element.Click
        Exit For
    Next oHTML_Element
    
    ' download translated document
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") ' Wait for 05 seconds
    For Each oHTML_Element In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-Bz112c-M1Soyc nCP5yc AjY5Oe LQeN7 sWFiQe")
        oHTML_Element.Click
        Exit For
    Next oHTML_Element
    
    ' Clean up and close IE
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set oHTML_Element = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: As an OT, I see that you use InternetExplorer, that got deprecated about 2 years ago. For today's standards I would strongly suggest to move to selenium. However, the one for VBA seems to be depracated as well since the update for chrome 115 about a month ago changed the infrastructure of it, making it useless in the way it used to be, it seems to be only updated properly in python, java, etc. So for this specific part, I'd encourage to do it in python.

Comment: Hi @Sgdva my requirement has to use a workbook with VBA to do the translations, as there are other code bocks that do further analysis. I have microsoft edge, but it easily start IE and initiaties download. Only those 2 points mentioned are troubling me.

Comment: I got into the same problem, sadly IE has security holes and like stated it's depracated as now (html code for example), only a few companies may still use it but most webpages are stopping to work due to not update the HTML for IE browser. You can use selenium for Edge, Chrome, etc. I would append an extra comment to what I think would need to be the course action to solve this.

Comment: With selenium you can easily do what you require for downloads, once they are downloaded you can move the files with VBA to the folder that you need and do the import of the workbook to you current macro and continue the workflow as needed.

Comment: I know about selenium to extract content from webpages. But we don't want a high end solution. I was testing Google Sheets GoogleTranslate() function which I tested with text and found it supports 50000 characters. But I don't know how to call it from VBA. If something like that is possible, then a chunk of text could be sent to Google Sheets GoogleTranslate() function and it's return value collected on every loop.