# Optimize code for speed that cleans and translates Excel Sheet using Regex and Google Translate

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, google-translate

I have a 2 column worksheet viz., `Interviewee` and `Verbatim` on which i am running the following code, that tries to clean any emojis, special characters, html tags and transcription tags using Regex, which works fast!

The `Verbatim` column can contain large text i.e. 2K+ characters.

There is a boolean flag `bTranslate` that is linked to a checkbox and if enabled, the code runs a Google Translate function to translate the `Verbatim` column text. Right now, i have to process it one row at a time and that too i have to split the text para into separate sentences for Google Translate function to work. This loop is what is taking a lot of time!

```
Sub CleanDataSheet()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim Regex As Object
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant, Arr2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    ' Initialize the RegExp object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With Regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        ' Combine all patterns into a single regex pattern
        .pattern = "\[.*?\]|<.*?>|[^\x20-\x7E]|-|/|-/-|:p"
    End With
    
    ' Set the worksheet and column range
    With wkData
        Set Rng = tblData.DataBodyRange  ' Change to your column range
        
        ' check if databodyrange is empty and 1 row
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("tblData[Verbatim]")) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Table is empty or does not exist!"
            GoTo cleanup
        End If
        
        ' remove duplicates from table
        On Error Resume Next
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        Arr = Rng.Value
        For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)
            
            ' do Regex replace
            Arr(i, 2) = Trim(Regex.Replace(Arr(i, 2), ""))
            DoEvents
            
            If Len(Arr(i, 2)) > 0 Then
            
                ' translate if true
                If bTranslate Then
                    
'                    Arr(i, 2) = GoogleTranslate(Trim(CStr(Arr(i, 2))), 0, "en")
'                    DoEvents
'                    split long text para into sentences and send to translate                     
                    If InStr(1, Trim(Arr(i, 2)), ". ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        Arr2 = Split(Trim(Arr(i, 2)), ". ")
                        If IsArray(Arr2) Then
                            For j = LBound(Arr2) To UBound(Arr2)
                                Arr2(j) = Translate(Trim(CStr(Arr2(j))), 0, "en") 'TranslateDataSheet
                                DoEvents
                            Next j
                            Arr(i, 2) = Trim(Join(Arr2, ". "))
                        Else
                            Arr(i, 2) = Translate(Trim(CStr(Arr(i, 2))), 0, "en")
                            DoEvents
                        End If
                    Else
                        Arr(i, 2) = Translate(Trim(CStr(Arr(i, 2))), 0, "en")
                        DoEvents
                    End If
                
                End If
            
            Else
                'blank out column 1 cell also so that remove blanks can work
                Arr(i, 1) = ""
            
            End If
'            DoEvents
        Next i
        
        
        ' transfer cleaned array data to Data sheet
        Rng.Clear
        Set Rng = tblData.DataBodyRange.Cells(1)
        Rng.Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)) = Arr
    
        ' Remove blank rows
        tblData.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
        On Error Resume Next
        Range("tblData[Verbatim]").EntireRow.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        tblData.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
    
        
        ' wrap Verbatim text
        With Range("tblData[Verbatim]")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = True
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
            .ColumnWidth = 50
            .RowHeight = 16.5
        End With
        
        MsgBox "Data cleaning successfully complete!", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
    End With
    
    
cleanup:
    ' Cleanup
    Set Regex = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & vbTab & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
    "Error Description: " & vbTab & Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error occurred!"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Err.Clear
    Resume cleanup
    
End Sub


Function Clean(val As String) As String
    val = Replace(val, "&quot;", """")
    val = Replace(val, "%2C", ",")
    val = Replace(val, "&#39;", "'")
    Clean = val
End Function

Function Translate$(sText As String, FromLang As String, ToLang As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim p1&, p2&, url$, resp$
    Const DIV_RESULT$ = "<div class=""result-container"">"
    Const URL_TEMPLATE$ = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=[from]&sl=[from]&tl=[to]&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q="
    
    url = URL_TEMPLATE & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(sText)
    url = Replace(url, "[to]", ToLang)
    url = Replace(url, "[from]", FromLang)
    resp = WorksheetFunction.WebService(url)
'    DoEvents
    
    p1 = InStr(resp, DIV_RESULT)
    If p1 Then
        p1 = p1 + Len(DIV_RESULT)
        p2 = InStr(p1, resp, "</div>")
        Translate$ = Clean(Mid$(resp, p1, p2 - p1))
    End If

cleanup:
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    Translate$ = sText
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume cleanup
End Function


' TRIED TESTING THIS FUNCTION ALSO
Public Function GoogleTranslate(strInput As String, strFromSourceLanguage As String, strToTargetLanguage As String) As String
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim objHTML As Object
    Dim objDivs As Object, objDiv As Object
    Dim strTranslated As String

    ' send query to web page
    strURL = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=" & strFromSourceLanguage & _
        "&sl=" & strFromSourceLanguage & _
        "&tl=" & strToTargetLanguage & _
        "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & strInput

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 'late binding
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ""

    Dim httpresponse() As Byte
    httpresponse = objHTTP.responseBody

    ' create an html document
    Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With objHTML
        .Open
        .Write objHTTP.responseText
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set objDivs = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        GoogleTranslate = GoogleTranslateRecursion(objDiv.ChildNodes)
        If GoogleTranslate <> "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If objDiv.className = "result-container" Then
            strTranslated = objDiv.innerText
            GoogleTranslate = strTranslated
            Exit For
        End If
    Next objDiv

    Set objHTML = Nothing
    Set objHTTP = Nothing

End Function


Function GoogleTranslateRecursion(pobjDivs As Object) As String
    Dim objDivs As Object, objDiv As Object
    Dim strTranslated As String
    
    GoogleTranslateRecursion = ""
    
    Set objDivs = pobjDivs
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        If objDiv.nodeName = "DIV" Then
            '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Z = objDiv.className
            '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Debug.Print Z
            strTranslated = GoogleTranslateRecursion(objDiv.ChildNodes)
            '#YGE 221001 for trialrun --  Debug.Print strTranslated
            If strTranslated <> "" Then
                GoogleTranslateRecursion = strTranslated
                Exit For
            End If
            
            If objDiv.className = "result-container" Then
                strTranslated = objDiv.innerText
                GoogleTranslateRecursion = strTranslated
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
    Next objDiv
End Function
```

I tried using the above Google Translate function, but it also takes the same amount of time i.e. 45 mins to go through 16K+ rows.

I need some code that can batch translate the whole excel sheet (Verbatim column) automatically without looping each cell.

any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked which part of the code is slow? approx 6 translations per second sounds not slow to me.

Comment: Have you found any limits on the length of text (number of characters) that your Google Translate function will accept and translate? Why are you splitting text in sentence chunks? In terms of performance, there is likely a trade-off between calls to the server and (average) length of text sent. Sending fewer, bigger chunks of text might improve performance. When concatenating text from multiple cells you'll need some sort of separator character to separate the translated result back into its components but judging by your code, that shouldn't present you with a problem.

Comment: @Shrotter the Translate() part is what is taking up time (45 mins), not the Regex.replace.

Comment: @DMM Thanks for bringing it up, as i had missed mentioning it in my post. The [Worksheet Webservice function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/webservice-function-0546a35a-ecc6-4739-aed7-c0b7ce1562c4#:~:text=If%20arguments%20result%20in%20a,error.) has a hard limit of 2048 characters, and that includes the URL (78) and URL+text encoding. Therefore to avoid translation errors, i had to resort to splitting long text paras into sentences. But it just increases time exponentially.

Comment: As an alternative, there is a `Documents` link on Google Translate that easily translates whole word/excel documents in seconds. But i don't know how to automate it using VBA, otherwise on click of a button, i could loop thru files in a folder and translate them one by one. My feeble attempt at doing so is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76921971/auto-translate-word-excel-document-to-english-with-google-translate-for-document) which BTW works!

Comment: Could you split the list up into multiple workbooks and either run multiple instances of the same code on the same/multiple machines?

Comment: @RyanWildry I did not understand your solution. Could you elaborate on what you meant?

Comment: You can halve the work into two workbook, and run two workbooks concurrently. There’s only so much work that be done on one thread. You could also split the work over multiple machines too

Comment: @RyanWildry there is only 1 workbook with a single sheet.

Comment: If you split it, and run separate processes it likely will go faster

Comment: The translate function is still taking time if I translate the sheet Verbatim column separately.